# bootstrap validator after ajax success

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrapvalidator-1000hz

In Bootstrap 3, I've a main DIV `#content-page` that contains a first `#button_1`. On `#button_1` click, Ajax loads a form on the same DIV, `#FORM`, that contains some required inputs and a submit button.

```
$('#FORM').validator().on('submit', function(event) { //do somethings.. });
```

Why `validator()` doesn't work?

```
$('#FORM').on('submit', function(event) { //do somethings.. }); ..instead 'this works fine..
```

How do I validate this form (with plugin validator)?

PS: plugin validator: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: I fixed writing <script> code in the [html] returns by Ajax success..

<form>
...
</form>

<script>
$('#form').validator();
</script>

..but I'd like to understand how do it on ajax success.